# Scroll Infinite with DOM recycle

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, responsive, viewport

I'm getting a little frustated because of implementing a nice scroll infinite browser performance after append hundreds/thousands of items. How could i do make DOM recycling without absolute position elements?

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/07/infinite-scroller

Trying to not reflow (or repaint) a non-visible items without a user scroll loss.

Furthermore, save scrolled position when comebacks from a history.back() (idea using pushState)

Is it possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Create a div wrapper for each item/content, with a specific height and width.  Divide the width of the container by the width of your item, so you know which row the item is on by its index.  Now, when you scroll, you look at the scroll height, and divide it by the height of your item, so you know which rows should be visible based on the height of your viewport.  Now, when an item is within the viewport, fill it with content, otherwise, remove its contents.  Do this render whenever you get the scroll event.  You may want to debounce it, because there are a lot of scroll events.

Comment: empty wrapper with fixed height like MANGO technique? https://shop.mango.com/gb/women/dresses_c55363448

Answer (score 1):

Below is a very good article on the implementation of infinite scroll considering DOM Recycling:
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/07/infinite-scroller
Hope this will help you understanding how dom recycling is done.